# Gradle refuses to sync with Android Project in IDEA 15

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradlew

I started a new Gradle-based Android project in IDEA CE 15, running the latest version of the Android plugin (10.1.3.0) on XUbuntu.

However, whenever I try to sync the project with gradle from IDEA, I get a "project sync failed" error, and I can't really do anything after that. Checking the logs reveals the following exception:

```
2015-11-16 14:30:29,172 [  53063]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - org.gradle.listener.ListenerBroadcast.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: org.gradle.listener.ListenerBroadcast.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:228)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:97)
at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:65)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:51)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:138)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:124)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:419)
at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:500)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$1.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:126)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:365)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
at org.jetbrains.ide.PooledThreadExecutor$1$1.run(PooledThreadExecutor.java:55)

2015-11-16 14:30:29,189 [  53080]   WARN - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask -  
2015-11-16 14:30:29,190 [  53081]   INFO - radle.project.ProjectSetUpTask - org.gradle.listener.ListenerBroadcast.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
2015-11-16 14:30:29,190 [  53081]   INFO - ls.idea.gradle.GradleSyncState - Sync with Gradle for project 'G.R.E.E.D' failed: org.gradle.listener.ListenerBroadcast.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V
```

I can, however, use gradle just fine from the terminal. Any ideas for what might be going wrong?

Comment: did you try to restart Android Studio and clean the project? (build>clean)

Comment: @buzeeg It throws the same error. If I try to run clean from the terminal, however, it works just fine. Still won't sync, however.

Also, I'm using IDEA 15 with the Android plugin, not Android Studio.

Comment: Did you solved the problem